# How to put PNG image with transparent background using HTML?

Tags: html

I have these two PNG images (Image 1: [eyemasktrans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxEXD.png) , Image 2:[dialogue_ughhh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg6iO.png)) which I already edited in Photoshop to make them transparent. But the problem is when I try to view on Chrome, the supposed transparent images appeared to have white backgrounds. Is they any way to fix this using just HTML? Thanks in advance! Below is my current code:

Other image I use: [girl_sleeping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4QFn.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .parallax {
      /* The image used */
      background-image: url("girl_sleeping.jpg");
      /* Set a specific height */
      min-height: 200px;
      /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <center> <img src="eyemasktrans.png" /> </center>
  <center> <img src="dialogue_ughhh.png" /> </center>

  <div class="parallax"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is the background of the site white?

Comment: Could you post an example image and a simple demo of it not working? The code included so far doesn't really tell us anything.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! 
Maybe the issue is with the images themselves ! try opening them with a photo viewer to see if they really have a transparent background. Maybe embed one of those images in your post to let us see where the problem is.

Comment: @DBS I already included the images and demo of the html

Comment: @Acemad thank you! I just included the images I use in the post. I try to view them in photo viewer and they indeed are transparent

Comment: @treyBake I'm not really sure about that. I already included the full html in the post btw

Comment: @Lily I would say the body is white... if a transparent image sits on top of a container with a white background, then the background will be white ...

Answer (score 0):

Your `eyemasktrans.png` and your `dialogue_ughhh.png` images are fine.  They have a proper alpha channel in the PNG.

I think the issue you're having is that the `.parallax` div is not sized corectly, and also has some weird background configurations with `fixed` and `center`, which cause it to appear like something is covering it while you scroll around the page.

I don't know what the desired effect is here, but if you size things correctly and set `z-index` as appropriate, you won't have a problem.

Additionally, I would suggest considering SVG for this task, since all your art is vector anyway.  You'll have a much faster load time.

(Issue is reproduced here:  http://jsfiddle.net/vr1qms9h/1/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the opacity attribute.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .parallax {
      /* The image used */
      background-image: url("http://thepotatoplace.ga/images/background.png");
      /* Set a specific height */
      min-height: 200px;
      /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      opacity: 0.65;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <center> <img src="eyemasktrans.png" /> </center>
  <center> <img src="dialogue_ughhh.png" /> </center>

  <div class="parallax"></div>

</body>

</html>
```